# I'm getting an error when creating my own widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

There is an error message in the problem section:A function body must be provided.how i can fix this red underline ?
[@ draws red under the sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdYWm.png)

Comment: Please provide your sample code as a code block instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon.

Try as follows:
`MyWidget({this,renk}); //you are missing a semicolon here.`